# Exponential weighted function on a groupby

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a data frame which has daily constituents of S&P 500. I would like to apply ewm function to calculate MACD as they did here:

https://towardsdatascience.com/implementing-macd-in-python-cc9b2280126a

Here is a slice of my data frame:

```
Date    Ticker  Company Name    Ending Price    Port_Weight
1988-12-30  09959910    Borden Inc. 29.625  0.23383237440144
1988-12-30  205212  ASARCO Incorporated 27.375  0.0609775201774554
1988-12-30  219546  Chrysler Corporation    12.875  0.3191417335057
1988-12-30  231565  Engelhard Corporation   5.1111102104187 0.0410319203440176
1988-12-30  231752  ENSERCH Corporation 18.875  0.0645416813614204
```

To compute ewm I'm grouping by 'Ticker' and try to use apply function:

```
df_target['EXP 12'] = df_target.groupby('Ticker').apply(lambda x: x['Ending Price'].ewm(span=12).mean().reset_index(level=0,drop=True))
```

But it returns the following TypeError I have no idea how to handle:

```
TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

Any hints would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `transform` on groupby series:

```
df_target['EXP 12'] = (df.groupby('Ticker')['Ending Price']
                         .transform(lambda x: x.ewm(span=12).mean())
                      )
```